# Increase number of items in 7Zip Extract to menu

Tags: windows, 7-zip

I was curious on how to expand the number of recent items in 7Zip's "Extract files..." menu to include more recent items in the "Extract to" field. Right now, the "Extract to" field only remembers the 8 most recent folder locations. It would be really nice to increase this to an arbitrary number. I'd imagine this is done via Registry edit; however I do not know how to proceed. See pictures below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since 7-Zip is an open-source program it is possible to check by looking at the [source code](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) itself.

After looking through the code I don't think the number of paths shown can be increased without re-compiling the source code as it appears to be a hard-coded value. Looking at the source of the relevant form (*ExtractDialog.cpp*) I found this:

```cpp
 #ifndef NO_REGISTRY
    static const int kHistorySize = 8;
 #endif
```

Followed by:

```cpp
 #ifndef NO_REGISTRY
    for (int i = 0; i < info.Paths.Size() && i < kHistorySize; i++)
       _path.AddString(info.Paths[i]);
 #endif
```

Here `_path` is the name of the combo box. So `kHistorySize` is limiting the number of items and its value does not come from a registry setting.

You could try contacting the developers of 7 Zip and requesting that they make the number of recent files configurable.